# EntityManager create query show unexpected token:

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using spring and hibernate, with JPG for database access. When using `namedQuery` I get an "unexpected token" error, but if I write the query directly in `entityManager`'s create method it is gives the correct result.

This is my pojo and query for retrieving user name:

```
 @NamedQueries(
    @NamedQuery( name="getUserName" , query="select u.name from User u")
  })

@Entity
@Table( name ="user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column( name="user_id")
    private int id;
    @Column( name="user_name")
    private String name;
    //getter setter
}
```

and this is code where I want to retrieve username.

```
entityManager.createQuery("getUserName").getResultList();
```

It produces this error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter: line 1:1: unexpected token: getUserName
! antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: getUserName
```

When I write the same query inside `entityManager.createQuery("write same query here ")` , it works. But I want to write query in named query and access it when needed. I am using spring and hibernate integration. Why does `namedquery` show unexepected token when used inside of `createquery` method of `entityManager`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`em.createQuery` is supposed to take in the JPQL. You should instead do

```
em.createNamedQuery("getUserName");
```